# where is gradle storing the android buildapk?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I use the command `gradle clean build`
it ends with BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but where can I find the build .apk?
Or how can I set up the build directory destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in //build/apk.  You'll need to do this outside of Android Studio since AS filters the directories and hides "apk".

Update: Android Studio no longer filters the output directory, so you can just drill into the build directory (under the app).